# Problem with sort algorithm(buying shop items)(Crashing)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, console-application

I have problem about little bit complex problem with sorting algorithm.
And my program non-stop crashing(sorry i'm bad at English). The goal of program
is to buy (from budget) most expensive item and sort every item to the list but, as you can see i'm suck at this and get an a crash from program(again sorry for rude).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double pare; //budget
int n; //numbers of articles
cin>>pare>>n;

string kod[n];//name of article

bool check[n]; //checker

double cena[n]; //price

int m,j; //max and extend for him(j)
m=cena[1];
j=0;

 for(int b = 0; b<n;b++){ //input
      cin>>cena[b];
}


for(int x = 0; x<n;n++){
    if(cena[x]==pare){
        pare-=cena[x];

           check[x] = true;
         }else if(cena[x]>pare){
             check[x] = false;

         }else if(cena[x] < pare){
                check[x] = true;
         }

for(int i2 = 0;i2<n;i2++){
    if(cena[i2] == true){
        if(m<cena[i2]){
            m=cena[i2];
            j=m;
        }
    }
}
 pare-=j;

}

 for(int i3 = 0; i3<n;i3++){   //output
     if(check[i3] == true){
        cout<<kod[i3]<< " " << cena[i3]<<endl;
    }
 }
 if(pare>0){
    cout<<pare<<endl;
 }




return 0;
}
```

Sorry if i something miss.

Comment: VLAs like `string kod[n];` are not part of C++. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: `m=cena[1];` assigns an uninitialised value to `m`.

Comment: "...as you can see i'm suck...". Even if that's true, it would be because I've spent time reading and/or running your code. The best way to get help is to clearly describe what you're having issues with and any errors you're receiving.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A novice programmer must learn to separate a task into parts. I suggest you learn to sort integers before you attempt to sort more complex structures.

Comment: `for(int x = 0; x<n;n++)` -- did you mean `x++`?

Answer (score -1):

```
 hello I'm not sure if I understood your code or not,
 but it supposed to be something like this 

 #include <iostream>
 //#include <string>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;

        int main(){

            double pare; //budget
            int n; //numbers of articles

            cin >> pare >> n;

            vector<string> kod(n); // name of article

            vector<bool> check(n); // checker

            vector<double> cena(n); // price

            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ //initilize
                kod[i] = "";
                check[i] = false;
                cena[i] = 0.0;
            }

            for(int b = 0; b < n; b++){ //input
                cin >> cena[b];
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < n; n++){
                if(cena[x] == pare){
                    pare -= cena[x];
                    check[x] = true;
                }
                else if(cena[x] > pare){
                    check[x] = false;
                }
                else if(cena[x] < pare){
                    check[x] = true;
                }
            }

            //max and extend for him(j)
            int m = cena[0];
            int j = 0;

            for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < n; i2++){
                    if(check[i2]){
                        if(m < cena[i2]){
                            j = m = cena[i2];
                        }
                    }
                }
                pare -= j;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ // to string 
                kod[i] = to_string(cena[i]);
            }

            for(int i3 = 0; i3 < n; i3++){   //output
                if(check[i3]){
                    cout << kod[i3] << " " << cena[i3] << endl;
                }
            }
            if(pare > 0){
                cout << pare << endl;
            }
        }
```